# Как сделать проверку на выигрышь 3 в ряд?

Tags: python, tkinter

Функция получает номер переставленного элемента и она должна проверить, получается ли по вертикали либо горизонтали так, что элементы с одинаковым цветом стоят в ряд (линию).

```
def check(i2, j2):
strok_left = 0
stolb_up = 0
strok_right = 0
stolb_down = 0
ball = 0
for j in range(i2, n):
    if a[i2][j] == a[i2][j+1]:
        strok_left+=1
    else:
        break
for j in range(0 ,i2+1, -1):
    if a[i2][j] == a[i2][j+1]:
        strok_right+=1
    else:
        break
if strok_right + strok_left >= 3:
    ball += (strok_right + strok_left)
print(ball)
```

А у меня  работает через раз. Пока что делал проверку только по строкам.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто перебираем все 8 направлений от текущей позиции и считаем ячейки которые равны текущей...

```
def check(field, row, col):
    n_rows = len(field)
    n_cols = len(field[0])
    # счетчики (себя учитываем изначально):
    counters = {(0,1): 1,    # по горизонтали
                (1,0): 1,    # по вертикали
                (1,1): 1}    # по диагонали
    # обход по всем 8ми направлениям 
    # (9ти, на самом деле, но комбинация 0:0 - это топтание на месте)
    for drow in (-1, 0, 1):
        for dcol in (-1, 0, 1):
            if drow == 0 and dcol == 0: 
                continue   # исключаем топтание на месте
            pos_row = row + drow
            pos_col = col + dcol
            # идём в выбранную сторону до тех пор пока ячейка поля
            # соответствует текущей, либо до границы поля
            while (0 <= pos_row < n_rows and 
                   0 <= pos_col < n_cols and 
                   field[row][col] == field[pos_row][pos_col]):
                # увеличиваем соответствующий направлению счётчик
                counters[(abs(drow), abs(dcol))] += 1
                # переходим к следующей ячейке в выбранном направлении
                pos_row += drow
                pos_col += dcol
    
    print(counters) # посмотрим на счётчики (просто для отладки)
    # проверка на то, что любой из счётчиков больше или равен 3
    return any(count >= 3 for count in counters.values())
    
a = [[0,0,1,0,0],
     [1,1,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,0,0],
     [0,0,1,1,0],
     [0,1,0,0,0]]
     
# распечатаем наше поле
print(" "*4, ": ".join(map(str, range(len(a[0])))), ":", sep="")
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    print(f"{i}: {row}")

for row, col in [(1,0), (2,2), (3,3), (4,1), (4,4)]:
    print(f"\nПроверяю позицию - ряд:{row}, столбец:{col} ...   ", end="")
    print("Результат проверки:", "Есть" if check(a, row, col) else "Нет", "3 в ряд")
```

Результат:

```
D:\Programming\Python\>python check3.py
    0: 1: 2: 3: 4:
0: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
1: [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
2: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
3: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
4: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Проверяю позицию - ряд:1, столбец:0 ...   {(0, 1): 3, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1}
Результат проверки: Есть 3 в ряд

Проверяю позицию - ряд:2, столбец:2 ...   {(0, 1): 1, (1, 0): 4, (1, 1): 3}
Результат проверки: Есть 3 в ряд

Проверяю позицию - ряд:3, столбец:3 ...   {(0, 1): 2, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 3}
Результат проверки: Есть 3 в ряд

Проверяю позицию - ряд:4, столбец:1 ...   {(0, 1): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 2}
Результат проверки: Нет 3 в ряд

Проверяю позицию - ряд:4, столбец:4 ...   {(0, 1): 3, (1, 0): 5, (1, 1): 1}
Результат проверки: Есть 3 в ряд
```